# LetsEncrypt and CakePhp issue

Tags: cakephp, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to install LetsEncrypt with cakephp and I'm having some issues.Let me describe:

First I'm installing LetsEncrypt on a server with CentOS 6.

As mentioned on several websites it needs a python upgrade from 2.6 to 2.7 as LetsEncrypt needs Python 2.7. Which I did.

Then if I run `./letsencrypt-auto` I get

> "No installers are available on your OS yet; try running "letsencrypt-auto certonly" to get a cert you can install manually"

I understand that this is normal as there is no installer for CentOS 6.

So I run `./letsencrypt-auto certonly`.A window appears.I have the choice between:

1. Place files in webroot directory
2. Automatically use a temporary webserver

So I press 1.Then I enter my domain name.And I see:

1. Enter a new webroot

I press ok and I see my root directory.I select `/root`

And then I have the following error:

> > Failed authorization procedure. www.example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient
> >     authorization :: Invalid response from
> >     http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/-CnpDIgxBB9EOH-BCssGOyiunFjnMlGLWhWw9roE4Ds:
> >     " 
> >     500 Internal Server Error  Inter"
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: www.example.com    Type:   unauthorized    Detail: Invalid
>   response from http://www.example.com/.well-known
>   /acme-challenge/-CnpDIgxBB9EOH-BCssGOyiunFjnMlGLWhWw9roE4Ds:
>   "    
>   500 Internal Server Error    
>   Inter"
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
>   contain(s) the right IP address.

And here comes cakephp. As mentioned I'm using cakephp. And it seems that for this specific issue you need to modify htaccess files as mentioned [here](https://github.com/cakephp/app/issues/368)

I need to add `"RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]"` as the first rewrite rule in the `root htaccess` and the `app/.htaccess`

Which I did.

```
root .htaccess: 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 
</IfModule>

app/.htaccess:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*)  webroot/$1    [L]
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 
 </IfModule>
```

But I still have the same problem

Any idea what I did wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `in the root htaccess and the app/.htaccess` The document root for your server should be `app/webroot`, the only htaccess file you should be changing  is (probably) `app/webroot/.htaccess`. Given what you're doing though - you could simply move your app out of the way to generate and install the cert, and then move it back.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried with app/webroot as "enter anew webroot"  but I still have the issue

Answer (score 1):

Cake's `webroot` has an `.htaccess` with a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` rule that means cake will not be called in for any request that matches an actual directory inside `webroot`.

So just place the `.well-known` directory and everything else that is needed inside the `webroot` directory, you should be able to access them fine without messing up with `.htaccess`.

PS. In some cases the file Let's encrypt requires is not served back as text, in which case you should enable the `headers` apache module (if not enabled already) and put the following rule in your apache or virtualhost config:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <LocationMatch "/.well-known/acme-challenge/*">
    Header set Content-Type "text/plain"
  </LocationMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I created a .well-known directory in webroot but I'm still having the issue :/ I also tried to modify the httpd.conf file, and same result

Comment: It's too difficult to guess what could be wrong without the exact error (look at the apache logs, 500 can be caused by a huge number of things). Also please try to revert your changes in each config, if you have a mixture of hacks it will be impossible to figure it out. BTW, this may sound trivial, but you don't really try to verify example.com, right?

Comment: PS : I put example.com to keep things anonymous, of course I have a real URL :)

Comment: I'm one step forward. I put everything into webroot as you mentioned but forgot to remove RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L] in others htaccess. So now when running ./letsencrypt-auto certonly it creates automatically a directory .well-known in webroot but this directory is empty (no acme challenge).

Comment: and letsencrypt returns the error : The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.myexample.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/BMCHuVRU5vzUDwPPBOH7hF-BfQZUX6dkvtbbCStW9AA: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

Comment: so basically the issue is that it is not creating the required file

Comment: You're not specifying the path to which the `letsencrypt` tool should save the files so that makes sense. Please read the tool's documentation over the `cert-only` mode of operation.